# HLS: How to detect EXT-X-DATERANGE in m3u8 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari, http-live-streaming

I want to add support to our our video streaming platform to detect `EXT-X-DATERANGE` tags that are present in our hls playlist files (m3u8) using javascript when video plays in safari browser. Can this be done?

On a side note, can `EXT-X-CUE-OUT`, `EXT-X-CUE-OUT-CONT`, `EXT-X-CUE-IN` tags found in m3u8 playlist be detected in javascript?